# how to change multiple div every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I tried to update my posts every 5 seconds, like the time is updated, how many users commented and how many likes.
this is the code i tried so far
    
    
    Some text1

```
<div id='poster' class='1'>
<input type='hidden' value='1' id='post_id'>
Some text1
</div>

<div id='poster' class='2'>
<input type='hidden' value='2' id='post_id'>
Some text2
</div>

<div id='poster' class='3'>
<input type='hidden' value='3' id='post_id'>
Some text3
</div>

<div id='poster' class='4'>
<input type='hidden' value='4' id='post_id'>
Some text4
</div>
```

in the body there is onload='refresh()'
here is what's in my java.js:

```
function refresh(){
var post_id = $("#post_id").val();
setTimeout(refresh_post(post_id),5000);
}

function refresh_post(post_id){
    $("."+post_id+"").load("post.php?post_id="+post_id);
}
```

but it only updates the first div the rest remains the same

Comment: `id ` should be unique, use` class` instead

Comment: have same class name for all divs and use each loop it will work

Comment: Nope they all have different class, the id is their class. Which means each have unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setinterval if you want to update post at every 5 second continuosly.

```
setInterval(function(){
 $('input:hidden').each(function() {
 var post_id = $(this).attr('id');
 refresh_post(post_id)
});
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Only update the first div, the other divs remains the same.

Comment: ok loop through all hidden..one thing id should be unique for all field in form..

Comment: updated the code above..try that

Comment: Ur code does not work, it doesnt update any of the div after applying ur code

Comment: WORKSSSSSSS THANKS SO MUCH, LOVE U!

Comment: Of topic, where do I get a typing gif like facebook, with transparent background?

Comment: check this: http://miscellaneousmischief.com/textinprogress.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the function or its reference which need to be execute to [window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

Also you need [`WindowTimers.setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

```
function refresh(){
    var post_id = $("#post_id").val();
    setInterval(function(){
        refresh_post(post_id)
    },5000);
}
```

*Identifiers in HTML must be unique*. You can assign conman class and the use [`class selector`](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) instead. You can store the `post_id` in custom `data-*` i.e. *data-id*  attributes which can be retrieved using `Element.dataset` property or jQuery's `.data(key)`

*HTML*

```
<div class='poster' data-id="1">
<input type='hidden' value='1'>
Some text1
</div>

<div class='poster'  data-id="2">
<input type='hidden' value='2' >
Some text2
</div>

<div class='poster'  data-id="3">
<input type='hidden' value='3'>
Some text3
</div>

<div class='poster'  data-id="">
<input type='hidden' value='4'>
Some text4
</div>
```

*Script*

```
function refresh(){
    $('.poster').each(function(){
        var post_id = this.dataset.id; // $("#post_id", this).val();
        var self = _this;
        setInterval(function(){
            $(self ).load("post.php?post_id="+post_id);
        },5000);
    });
}
```

Comment: does not work, only updates the first div, the rest remains the same.

Comment: @RichardCheng, see updated answer

Comment: Totally does not do anything after updating my script to the script u made.

Comment: @RichardCheng, Did you updated the HTML?

Comment: Yea the answer below worked, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Method getElementsByClassName() returns a set of DOM elements that have a certain class name.

```
setInterval(function(){

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("poster");
for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    var post_id = elements[i].id;
    refresh_post(post_id)
}

}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

**old_html** is div id which is  you want dynamic load.

**newContent** geting dynamic div from another page.

```
<script>

    setInterval( function() {
        $('div#old_html').load('http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?>/pbartest.php #newContent');
    }, 5000);  </script>
```